# Parameter error when resolving AD user

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to resolve why I get an error with the following script.  I should prefix this statement by saying that the script does correctly output and function, but always prefixed by the same number of errors.

The CSV file being used is auto-generated and the headers are not on the first line, which is why I have to skip the first 4 lines.

Here is the script:

```
# Getting the name of PCs in the DNS column.
$data = Get-Content -Path c:\admin\scripts\windows\test.csv |
        Select-Object -Skip 4 |
        Out-String |
        ConvertFrom-Csv |
        Select-Object -Property DNS -Unique

$dns = $data.DNS

# REMOVES DOMAIN NAME AND LEAVES JUST THE HOST/USERNAME
[regex]$myregex = "\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S$"

$dns2 = foreach ($DNS in $dns) {
    $myregex.split($dns)
}

$getemail = foreach ($DNS in $dns2) {
    Get-ADUser $DNS -Properties mail | Select-Object -Property mail -Unique
}

Send-MailMessage -Attachments c:\admin\scripts\windows\test.csv -From admin@mydomain.com -To $getemail.mail -Subject "UPDATES OF NON-SUPPORTED APPLICATIONS REQUIRED" -SmtpServer smtp.mydomain.com
```

This will get the email address for the users and send a copy of a report to each of them.  It actually works, but for every correct email address, there is a corresponding error:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity' to the target. Exception 
setting "Identity": "Cannot validate argument on parameter: 'Identity'. The 
argument is null or empty.

Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
```

I would just like to stop the errors to avoid any confusion for others who run this script.

Answer (score 0):

Your input file contains non-existing user identities. To have `Get-ADUser` skip over them without complaining use `-Filter` instead of the implicit `-Identity`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$DNS'" -Properties mail |
  Select-Object -Property mail -Unique
```

or use `-LDAPFilter` with [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243299) if you're not sure which attribute exactly to match:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$DNS)" -Properties mail |
  Select-Object -Property mail -Unique
```

---

**Edit:** To extract the part before a hyphen in a string it might be better to do something like this:

```
$getemail = $data.DNS | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace '-.*'
} | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$_)" -Properties mail |
    Select-Object -Property mail -Unique
}
```

---

Some additional comments on the rest of your code. The first `foreach` loop uses the same variable for loop variable and element list:

```
$dns2 = foreach ($DNS in $dns) {
    $myregex.split($dns)
}
```

Don't do that. PowerShell variable names aren't case-sensitive.

Also, your regular expression

```
[regex]$myregex = "\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S$"
```

can be simplified like this:

```
[regex]$myregex = "\S{16}$"
```

or (if you don't care about the exact number of characters) like this:

```
[regex]$myregex = "\S+$"
```

Comment: Thank you!  I agree with the variable names, I plan to change them before I go live with this script.  I suppose I was just in a hurry when I started this one.  The regex suggestion is also great, thanks!  My regex is def rusty.  Unfortunately, neither the filter or ldap filter work.  It comes back with the correct mail addresses, but also an equivalent error:  get-aduser : The search filter cannot be recognized

Comment: Actually, after doing more testing, I think the issue is at the regex part of the code.  If I output just after that point, it looks like I am getting 2 extra blank lines, which would explain why I get 2 errors when I run get-aduser.  So in the source file the DNS field is the name of a user's computer and there can be multiple lines per user, which is why I added the -unique, but maybe there is a more efficient way to modify the output of the DNS column.  The field would look similar to:  jsmith-t5600.mycpy.com and I want to filter out from - to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again Ansgar!

After a little more tweaking, I incorporated your suggestions into the script and this is the one that now works perfectly:

```
$data = Get-Content -path c:\admin\scripts\windows\test.csv | select-object` 
-skip 4 | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Csv | select-object -property DNS -unique

$getuser = $data.dns | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '-.*'}

$getemail = foreach($dns in $getuser) {get-aduser -filter "(samaccountname` 
-eq '$dns')" -properties mail | select-object -property mail -unique} 

send-mailmessage -attachments c:\admin\scripts\windows\test.csv` 
-from admin@mydomain.com -to $getemail.mail`
-subject "UPDATES OF NON-SUPPORTED APPLICATIONS REQUIRED"`
-smtpserver smtp.mydomain.com
```

I appreciate your assistance!

JC